# How can I get a username from the clients in java server

Tags: java, server

I'm developing an android application where the user has to put his username first and click "connect" then the server has an ArrayList of online users' usernames and it has to check if this username has been used before or not, if not it accepts the connection and adds the username to the arraylist otherwise it sends an error message. I don't know how to connect the code.
here's the server side:

```
public class server {
private boolean usernameb;
private ArrayList<String> users;
private Hashtable outputStreams = new Hashtable();
public server (int port) throws IOException {
    listen (port);      
}
static public void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    //to get the port from the command line
    int port = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );
    //creating new object to accept connections
    new server (port); 
}
//method to check for duplicates username
private boolean dupl (String username) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
        String temp = users.get(i);
        if (temp.equals(username)){
            this.usernameb = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.usernameb = true;
        }
    }
    return usernameb;
}
private void listen(int port) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverS = new ServerSocket (port);
    System.out.println( "Server is ready on : "+ serverS);

    while (true) {
    //Getting next connection
    Socket clientS = serverS.accept();
    System.out.println( "Connection has been accepted from " + clientS );
    //to write data to the other side
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(clientS.getOutputStream());
    outputStreams.put(clientS, dout);
    //creating a new thread for this connection
    new serverThread( this, clientS);
    }
}
void removeConnection(Socket socket) {
    synchronized (outputStreams) {
        System.out.println("Removing connection of :  " + socket);
        outputStreams.remove(socket);
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Error closing : " + socket);
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
Enumeration getOutputStreams() {
    return outputStreams.elements();
    }
void sendToAll(String message) {
    synchronized (outputStreams) {
        for (Enumeration e = getOutputStreams(); e.hasMoreElements();) {

            DataOutputStream dout = (DataOutputStream) e.nextElement();
            try {
                dout.writeUTF(message);
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the server thread code

```
public class serverThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
private server server;
public serverThread (server server, Socket socket) {
    this.server = server;
    this.socket = socket;
    //start the thread
    start();
}
public void run() {
    try {
        //creating DateInputStream to recieve what the client types
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            //reading messages
            String message = din.readUTF();
            //printing the message
            System.out.println( "Sending " + message);
            //send the message to other clients
            server.sendToAll(message);
        }
        }
    catch(EOFException ie) {

        } 
    catch( IOException ie ) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
        } 
    finally {
        //closing connection
        server.removeConnection(socket);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "connect the code"? What should it do, where is it going wrong and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some protocol to deal with the client, even a very simple one, as you are writing both the client and the server it should not be a problem.

in the server thread is should be some thing like that:

```
        while (true) {
        //reading messages
        String message = din.readUTF();
        String action=Protocol.getRespone(message);
```

This bit will take the message from the client, 
and say, for example, if it is in the format of &login:username it will check it against the server database, do the neccisery modifactions to it, and return "User name already in use" if in user, else "User %username% connected succesfuly". and if the message is in &message: "bla bla bla" it will act normally, eg return what ever you want.